# Are CodeIgniter database sessions more secure even if cookies are encrypted?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

### Question 1

Basically, what I'm asking is: Is `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` more secure even if `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;`?

I keep stumbling on blogs, Stackoverflow posts, and even CI Docs that claim `$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` is more secure, but it seems that the location `user_data` is stored (in cookie or in database) shouldn't quite matter from a security standpoint if the cookie is encrypted anyway.

### Question 2

If you set `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;` and inspect the cookies, regardless of the value of `$config['sess_use_database']`, there is a (what appears to be md5) hash stuck on the end of the cookie - here's an example:

```
a:4{
  s:10:"session_id";
  s:32:"a2caac03fc72d709ac280540a09d8ed7";
  s:10:"ip_address";
  s:9:"127.0.0.1";
  s:10:"user_agent";
  s:100:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.14 Safari/537.4";
  s:13:"last_activity";
  i:1347228760;
}7aa8ebe3fc462bd86c0c0544a969cbda
```

What is the significance of `7aa8ebe3fc462bd86c0c0544a969cbda`? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1**
That depends on what you consider secure.

The custom data you set, will be stored in the database, but session_id, ip_address, user_agent and last_activity will still be stored in the cookie. If you consider these data compromising, then the answer is yes. Otherwise the answer would be no.

**Question 2**
It's a hash of the serialized data containing your session data combined with your encryption key. This is used to make sure that the cookies data has not been tampered with.

Comment: +1 and instead of answering to offer additional input, I just want to add that people consider the database method more secure because you can absolutely verify the validity of a session, whereas with a cookie, even an encrypted one, has the potential (however slight) to be forged.

Comment: and a database session is not limited by a 4kb limit like a cookie is - which can sometimes cause unexpected issues